# How to store information from a loop function?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, loops

Could you please help me store the 'name' and 'gender' into a new pandas.DataFrame from the following loop's outcome?

Here's my loop function:

```
def predict_gender_combined(name_input):
  d_2=GenderDetector()

  g_2=d_2.get_gender(name_input)
  g_3= Genderize().get([name_input])
  print(f'{g_2}\n{g_3}')
  print('---------------')
  return(g_2,g_3)

name_list= ['Anna', 'Maria']
 for name in name_list:
  _=predict_gender_combined(name)
```

outcome:

```
Person(title=None, first_name='anna', last_name=None, email=None, gender='f')
[{'name': 'Anna', 'gender': 'female', 'probability': 0.98, 'count': 383713}]
---------------
Person(title=None, first_name='maria', last_name=None, email=None, gender='f')
[{'name': 'Maria', 'gender': 'female', 'probability': 0.98, 'count': 334287}]
---------------
```

Goal: To create a new pandas.DataFrame, with first column "name" and second column "gender"

```
name   gender
Anna    f
Maria   f
```

Attempt:

```
prediction_list = list() 
name_list= ['Anna', 'Maria'] 
for name in name_list: 
  prediction=predict_gender_combined(name) 
  prediction_list.append(prediction)
```

Comment: What do you want to store as the "name" and the "gender"? Where do you want to store them? Do you want a list of `Person` objects or a list of dictionaries?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I would like to store "name" and "gender" of each Person in a new df, as a list of dictionaries

Comment: Does `df` in your question mean a [`pandas.DataFrame`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html)? If so, you should edit the question to make that clearer, maybe adding the corresponding tag.

Comment: first create normal list  and use `append()` in loop. And after loop conver it to DataFarame. OR first create DataFrame with names in column and later use `apply()` instead of loop to genereate new column

Comment: @furas I tried this, but it didn't work:

prediction_list = list()
name_list= ['Anna', 'Maria']
for name in name_list:
  prediction=predict_gender_combined(name)
prediction_list.append(prediction)

Comment: and what did you get in `prediction_list` ? if you get wrong values then problem is function `predict_gender_combined`

Comment: I see you add it to question - you have wrong indentation - `append()` has to be inside `for`-loop but you run it after `for`-loop

Comment: @furas I got "[None, None]" in prediction_list

Comment: it shows that all your problem is `predict_gender_combined()`. You show that it return `return (g_2,g_3)` but results shows that it `return None` or maybe it doens't have `return` and then it returns `None` as default.

Comment: I made a silly mistake in the code. prediction_list now returns this "[(Person(title=None, first_name='anna', last_name=None, email=None, gender='f'),
  [{'name': 'Anna',
    'gender': 'female',
    'probability': 0.98,
    'count': 383713}]),
 (Person(title=None, first_name='maria', last_name=None, email=None, gender='f'),
  [{'name': 'Maria',
    'gender': 'female',
    'probability': 0.98,
    'count': 334287}])]" -- yet I still have to create a df

Comment: All fixed!! df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(prediction_list)

Answer (score 0):

This is what dictionary comprehensions are for.

```py
# This := syntax is an "assignment expression" that is available in Python 3.8+
result = {"name": predicted[0]["name"], "gender": predicted[0]["gender"] for predicted := predict_gender_combined(name) in name_list}
```

It is, however *a lot*. Let's write that out so it's a little easier to read:

```py
result = {}
for name in name_list:
    predicted = predict_gender_combined(name)
    result["name"] = predicted[0]["name"]
    result["gender"] = predicted[0]["gender"]
```

Comment: thanks a lot, however it doesn't seem to be working. I get this error "TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable"

Comment: @user14419478 if you get `NoneType error` then your function `predict_gender_combined` returns `None` instead of gender.

Comment: @user14419478 this probably means that I've poorly understood what the output from `predict_gender_combined` is. You should be able to parse that somehow to get the name and gender from the resulting object.

Comment: @AdamSmith the prediction list returns this "[(Person(title=None, first_name='anna', last_name=None, email=None, gender='f'), [{'name': 'Anna', 'gender': 'female', 'probability': 0.98, 'count': 383713}]), (Person(title=None, first_name='maria', last_name=None, email=None, gender='f'), [{'name': 'Maria', 'gender': 'female', 'probability': 0.98, 'count': 334287}])]" -- -- yet I still have to create a df

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to make some assumptions on what you're hoping to do here:

1. you're trying to get a list of dictionaries
2. each dictionary holds a name and holds a count for the number of times the names occurred in `name_list`.

I'm not sure what the `probability` key is used for, and I don't know what the `g_3` is used for in your defined function, so I'll have to leave that up to you. But given these assumptions, here's what I would recommend:

If you really want a list of dictionaries, that's fine, but it would probably be easier to first make a dictionary of dictionaries and then convert it to a list, e.g.,

```py
{
"Tim": {'name': 'Tim', 'gender': 'M', 'probability': 0.0, 'count': 4}, "Sam": {'name': 'Sam', 'gender': 'F', 'probability': 0.0, 'count': 5},
...
}
```

Then, you could use the following code:

```py
name_list=list_of_users
name_dict={}
for name in name_list:
  test_list=predict_gender_combined(name)
  if name in name_dict:
    name_dict[name] =  {'name': name, 'gender': test_list[0], 'probability': 0.0, 'count': 1}
  else:
   name_dict[name]['count'] += 1

final_list=list(name_dict.values())
```

Hope that gets you started.

Comment: There was some activity on this question while I typed up my response, so it would need to be adjusted.